# How to configure #IISManager with modern & advanced techniques?

Tags: iis, iis-manager

#IISManager functionalities to be elaborated for all types of users for the development & deployment purpose.

I tried many functionalities but didn't get to know what's the standard flow of #IISManager.

Comment: I wonder what kind of answer you are looking for. IIS Manager is just the GUI application to assist you modify IIS configuration, so you can use it following your intuition and Microsoft docs, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-the-iis-manager-in-iis-7-and-iis-8 As its current look-and-feel was introduced in Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008, nobody uses "modern and advanced" to describe such a decade-old stuff.

Comment: Here are some more articles about IIS Manager that might help you: [IIS Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/jj635847(v=ws.11)).